# Adding pagination

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pagination

Possibly a big ask, but wondering if someone could assist me with adding pagination to the below. I'm fairly new with MVC.

https://github.com/panique/tiny

So far, I've added Limit on the model but don't know what how to pass page number etc after that.

https://github.com/panique/tiny/blob/master/application/model/model.php

Comment: use templating engine (twig, smarty) to pass variable from controller to html, use AJAX to execute your pagination function.

Comment: I don't think I knowledgeable to use template engines yet. Would be nice if someone could update the git with the code. As I said, it might be too much of an ask. New to MVC. Thanks anyway.

Comment: My advice would be to stay away from panique's code. It's terrible and will actually give you a wrong impression about what MVC is.

Comment: @tereško OK. Have you got any suggestions for a micro framework like his which is not terrible?

Comment: In general, I would actually recommend trying to build your project purely on composer packages ([this tutorial](https://github.com/PatrickLouys/no-framework-tutorial) might help), but if you really need a framework, I guess you could try picking apart [Silex](https://silex.sensiolabs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you confident enough with OOP? If yes why don't you start learning Laravel?

https://laravel.com/

This would be a basic example of pagination with Laravel:

```
$users = User::paginate(15);
```